# How to output the variable within space by using command "sed"

Tags: shell, sed

Here is a file as follow:

```
# cat test.txt
test
```

I wanna append a line follow the "test" using 'sed' command like this:

Command(here is a space between 'A' and 'B'):

```
# ARG='A B'
# sed -i '/^test/a\'${ARG}'' test.txt
```

But I get this:

```
sed: can't read B: No such file or directory
```

I want the result `cat` like this:

```
# cat test.txt
test
A B
```

How to do it with 'sed' command? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ARG='A B'
sed 's/^test$/&\n'"$ARG"'/' test.txt
```

> `&`: refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched

Output to stdout:

```
test
A B
```